# Print value of variables in the previous frames

Tags: r

It's possible to list variables in the previous frame via:

```
ls(parent.frame())
```

For example such call prints:

```
[1] "f" "x"
```

Is it possible to get value of these variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the following commands should work.

```
parent.frame()$f
parent.frame()$x
```